# Which Content Search Manager would be better to use for Solr search?

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore8

for me it looks like luck of documentation about Content Search API for sitecore. 
I have Sitecore instance with all settings for use SOLR search and I would like to have a search for bucket items. 
I am confused that Content Search should I use for implement my search logic 
ContentSearchManager or SolrContentSearchManager ?

```cs
using (var context = SolrContentSearchManager.GetIndex(_searchIndexName).CreateSearchContext())
{
    IQueryable<MyClass> query = context.GetQueryable<MyClass>().Where(p => p.MyProd.Contains("name"));
    return query;
}
```

In both cases CreateSearchContext return IProviderSearchContext interface. 
I have a filling that sitecore relay on configuration setting and it no difference. Am I right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ContentSearchManager` is ok for `Solr` as well. It allows you to switch between `Lucene` and `Solr` without too many changes to your code.

I've never used `SolrContentSearchManager`.